# How to select the data from exact partitions?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In the table tbl_dtdata I was created 7 partitions. I want to select the data from first partition p_APR. I was tried this query.`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_dtdata PARTITION (p_Apr);` But It is returning syntax error. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: AFAIK partition selection is only available from MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Checkout following link that might be use full to you:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/